# Display data in return() from JSON retrieved render()

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

So I'm having a problem displaying data retrieved from an API as JSON.
Below is the code. When I try to display the values in the render function, it doesn't display as it is undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

render() {
    var request = require("request");
    var urlCardName = encodeURIComponent(this.props.card.card_name);
    var url = "./query.php?cardName=" + urlCardName;
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var cardResponse = JSON.stringify(body);
            var cardName = body.cardName.toString();
            var cardCount = body.cardCount.toString();
            console.log(cardCount);
        }
    })

    return(<div>
        Card Count: {cardCount}
        Card Name: {cardName}
    </div>);
}
}
export default Test;
```

The problem is that I don't think I fully understand how to take variables from JSON and display them as strings in the render function.

How can I display these values?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the card count get logged correctly in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By standards, you put AJAX requests in `componentDidMount` and update the state from there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import request from 'request';

class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null // empty data
        }

    }

    componentDidMount(){

        var urlCardName = encodeURIComponent(this.props.card.card_name);
        var url = "./query.php?cardName=" + urlCardName;
        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var cardResponse = JSON.stringify(body);
                var cardName = body.cardName.toString();
                var cardCount = body.cardCount.toString();

                // Update the state
                this.setState( { cardName, cardCount } );
            }
        })

    }

    render() {

        // Object destructing 
        let { cardName, cardCount } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                Card Count: {cardCount}
                Card Name: {cardName}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. I'm still working my head around working with the state.

Answer (score 1):

1- You will need to save data from api into component state, and in react once you update the component state, component will render again and you will be able to see your data.

It is better to read more about React and component [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

2- You will need to move your request call to `componentDidMount` lifecycle function, this function will be called directly after the component is mounted, and you can update the component state inside this function, also it is critical to avoid updating state inside render function as it will end up with infinite render calls

It is also good to read more about component [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Finally you can try the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cardName: '',
      cardCount: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var request = require("request");
    var urlCardName = encodeURIComponent(this.props.card.card_name);
    var url = "./query.php?cardName=" + urlCardName;
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var cardResponse = JSON.stringify(body);
            this.setState( cardName: body.cardName.toString());
            this.setState( cardCount: body.cardCount.toString());
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(<div>
        Card Count: {this.state.cardCount}
        Card Name: {this.state.cardName}
    </div>);
  }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: I got "super() outside of class constructor (5:2)" error.

Comment: Yeah my bad there was a typo in `constructor` i fixed it

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining why you moved the code from render() to componentDidMount().

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you don't want that data to live within its own component (ex. `<CardCount />`), you can wrap `cardCount` in `<h1>` tags like: `<h1>{cardCount}</h1>` .

Comment: Currently it's living in its own component. But I'm unsure as to how I can pass it onward in react. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how that component is set up obviously, but you could do something like this: `<CardCount cardCount={cardCount} />`. You can access the cardCount prop within `<CardCount />` by using `this.props.cardCount` or `props.cardCount` depending on if you are extending `Component` or just a pure function.